# Send multi-row form data using jQuery (ajax, json) and Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

JSP:

```
<script>
    var queryString = JSON.stringify($("#testForm").serializeArray());
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"testUrl",
        data : queryString,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(){
          //...
        },
        error: function(request,status,error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
<script>
<form id="testForm">
     <input type="text" name="a" value="1" />
     <input type="text" name="b" value="1" />
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="a" value="2" />
     <input type="text" name="b" value="2" />
</form>
```

DTO:

```
public class TestForm {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    //Getters and setters
    //...
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
   @Autowired
   Service service;

   @RequestMapping("/testUrl")
   public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> testUrl(@RequestBody List<TestForm> testForms) {
        HashMap<String, Object> chkVal = Service.testUrl(testForms);
        return chkVal;
   }
}
```

I want to make the JSP to send multi-row data into the Spring controller using JSON, but these codes aren't working. The data are repeated objects.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSP you want to replace the following line `url:"testUrl",` with the URL to the controller method: e.g. `url:"http://localhost:8080/testUrl"`.

Then, in your `TestForm` model, rename the properties to `name` and `value` (because you will receive something like `[{"name": "a", "value": 1}, ...]`).

After that it should work. As a side note, you probably don't want to call the AJAX right after you load the page. It probably would be better to fire that on a submit button click or something like that, but of course that is up to you and your use case.